# Passport JS - Login always going through the failureRedirect route

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I am currently developing a web application of my own.

I am successfully registering users with the appropriate username, hash and salt properties. However, when attempting to log in, I am always redirected to the failureRedirect route (even when I know that I am getting the usernames and passwords correct).

I've gone through StackOverflow and my code with a fine comb but I am just not seeing what is wrong.

Below is the configuration on my  app.js

```
const   express         = require('express'),
        app             = express(), 
        mongoose        = require('mongoose'),
        bodyParser      = require('body-parser'),
        passport        = require('passport'), 
        LocalStrategy   = require('passport-local'),    
        User            = require('./models/user');

//CONFIGURATION OF mongoose, bodyParser, ejs and setting the use of public folders for CSS; 
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/kinetic", {useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true }); 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs'); 
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); 

//PASSPORT CONFIG 
app.use(require("express-session")({ 
    secret: "Any message can go here apparently",   
    resave: false, 
    saveUninitialized: false
})); 
app.use(passport.initialize()); 
app.use(passport.session()); 
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate())); //comes from passport-local-mongoose
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser()); 
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());
```

Below is a copy of my login form (which I am getting correctly with my get request):

```
<form action="/login" method="POST">    
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <input type="password" name="password">
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

As you can see, I am passing in the appropriate name properties for passport.

Below is a copy of my post request using passport's middleware:

```
router.post("/login", passport.authenticate("local", {
    successRedirect: "/campgrounds",
    failureRedirect: "/loginfail"
    }), (req, res)=>{ 
});
```

Below is a copy of the json of a registered user:

```
{
  followers: [],
  _id: 5e978583865a1124c8a61d46,
  username: 'bob',
  bio: 'bob',
  salt: 'f9e38abf7383aa431f42bf3a30ecdb037c5876f15c44ff64e961e5759bcbae54',
  hash: '379702439bf8e1.........dd2fc7e4f50',
  __v: 0
}
```

EDIT: ./models/user

```
const   mongoose                = require('mongoose'), 
        passportLocalMongoose   = require('passport-local-mongoose'); 

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {type: String, unique: true}, 
    password: String,  
}); 

UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose); 

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

I am completely stumped, although I can imagine that the solution is just under my nose.

Comment: need to see your ```User.authenticate``` function, share your ```models/user``` file. Or just take help from this link https://github.com/arjun-707/login-logout-jwt-nodejs

Comment: Hi Arjun. Thanks for replying. I've added the models/user.

Comment: I am not sure, but just check if the collection name is Users instead of User

Answer (score 0):

**Soo... I think I may have found out what was wrong:**

In my main file (app.js), I configured my routes at the top of the page (I didn't show my whole file because I never thought it would be necessary (I am new to coding, if you never guessed).

My *old* app.js looked something like this:

```
const   express         = require('express'),
        app             = express(), 
        mongoose        = require('mongoose'),
        bodyParser      = require('body-parser'),
        passport        = require('passport'), 
        passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose'), 
        LocalStrategy   = require('passport-local'),    
        User            = require('./models/user');

//REQUIRE ROUTE FILES:
const   exerciseRoutes  = require('./routes/exercises'), 
        commentRoutes   = require('./routes/comments'),
        indexRoutes     = require('./routes/index'); 

//TAKE NOTE OVER HERE: 
    app.use('/', indexRoutes); 
    app.use('/exercises', exerciseRoutes); 
    app.use('/exercises/:slug/comments', commentRoutes);


//CONFIGURATION OF mongoose, bodyParser, ejs and setting the use of public folders for CSS; 
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/kinetic", {useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true }); 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs'); 
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); 

//PASSPORT CONFIG 
app.use(require("express-session")({ 
    secret: "Any message can go here apparently",   
    resave: false, 
    saveUninitialized: false
})); 
app.use(passport.initialize()); 
app.use(passport.session()); 
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate())); //comes from passport-local-mongoose
passport.use(User.createStrategy()); 
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser()); 
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());

app.get('/', (req, res)=>{
    res.send("HOME PAGE!")
}); 

app.use((req, res, next)=>{
    res.locals.currentUser = req.user; 
    next()
});


//SET UP PORT: 
app.listen(3000, ()=>{
    console.log("Connected to kinetic!")
})
```

All I needed to do was move this ...

```
app.use('/', indexRoutes); 
        app.use('/exercises', exerciseRoutes); 
        app.use('/exercises/:slug/comments', commentRoutes);
```

... just above my port/app listener and *voilà*

Now my app.js file looks like this:

```
const   express         = require('express'),
        app             = express(), 
        mongoose        = require('mongoose'),
        bodyParser      = require('body-parser'),
        passport        = require('passport'), 
        passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose'), 
        LocalStrategy   = require('passport-local'),    
        User            = require('./models/user');

//REQUIRE ROUTE FILES:
const   exerciseRoutes  = require('./routes/exercises'), 
        commentRoutes   = require('./routes/comments'),
        indexRoutes     = require('./routes/index'); 

//CONFIGURATION OF mongoose, bodyParser, ejs and setting the use of public folders for CSS; 
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/kinetic", {useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true }); 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs'); 
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); 

//PASSPORT CONFIG 
app.use(require("express-session")({ 
    secret: "Any message can go here apparently",   
    resave: false, 
    saveUninitialized: false
})); 
app.use(passport.initialize()); 
app.use(passport.session()); 
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate())); //comes from passport-local-mongoose
passport.use(User.createStrategy()); 
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser()); 
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());

app.get('/', (req, res)=>{
    res.send("HOME PAGE!")
}); 

app.use((req, res, next)=>{
    res.locals.currentUser = req.user; 
    next()
});

//MUST BE BELOW PASSPORT CONFIGURATION! 
app.use('/', indexRoutes); 
app.use('/exercises', exerciseRoutes); 
app.use('/exercises/:slug/comments', commentRoutes);

//SET UP PORT: 
app.listen(3000, ()=>{
    console.log("Connected to kinetic!")
});
```